# How i can get object serializer in has_permission (Django)

Tags: python, django

Sorry for my english. I beginner in django, and i dont understand why it dont work. I create custom permissions. In this permission i need get values of object serializer. For example, its my view:

```
class ProposeFromDealer(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CatInHouseSerializer
    permission_classes = (custom_permissions.CheckExistCatInHouse, permissions.IsAuthenticated)
```

my custom permission

```
class CheckExistCatInHouse(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'Cat not exist in this house'

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, object):
        current_house = object.house
        house = House.objects.get(id=current_house.id)
        cats_in_house = house.cats.values_list('id')
        current_cat_id = object.cat.id

        if current_cat_id in cats_in_house:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

It method return False if cat doesnt exist in this house and true if exist. But permission success.

I can do method like this:

```
  def has_permission(self, request, view):
```

but i dont know how i can get `object` in this method?

Like this:

```
class CheckExistCatInHouse(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'Cat not exist in this house'

    def has_opermission(self, request, view):
         object = get_serializer_object() #how i can get object ???
        current_house = object.house
        house = House.objects.get(id=current_house.id)
        cats_in_house = house.cats.values_list('id')
        current_cat_id = object.cat.id

        if current_cat_id in cats_in_house:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the [`has_object_permission()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#examples) method like this:

```
class CheckExistCatInHouse(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'Cat not exist in this house'

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # __________________________________________^
        cats_in_house = obj.house.cats.values_list('id')
        current_cat_id = obj.cat.id

        return current_cat_id in cats_in_house
```

**Important:** Then in your `view` you should call [`self.check_object_permissions(request, obj)`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions) in order to call this permission (`CheckExistCatInHouse`).

*Note*: I also simplified your permission. There is no need of redundant queries and `if` statements.